# Calculate an unconditional probability given only the conditional probability

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be jointly absolutely continuous random variables. Suppose X~Exponential(2) and P(Y > 5 | X = x) = $$e^{-3x}$$. Compute P(Y > 5).

I've computed P(Y > 5) as follows:

P(Y > 5) = P(Y > 5 | X = $x_1$) + ... + P(Y > 5 | X = $x_n$) = $\int_0^\infty e^{-3x} dx = \frac13$

However, I'm not sure the answer is correct, since I did not have to use the fact that X~Exponential(2). Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P\{Y > 5\mid X = x\} = \exp(-3x)$, then 
$$P\{Y > 5\} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{Y > 5\mid X = x\} f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx
= \int_0^\infty \exp(-3x) \cdot 2\exp(-2x)\,\mathrm dx$$
and so the answer *does* depend on the distribution of $X$. The above 
*is*  an application of
the law of total probability for continuous random variable as @Patrick says in
his answer, but *your* answer of $\frac{1}{3}$ is incorrect. You are
adding up *conditional* probabilities conditioned on different events,
and that is *not* what the law of total probability does.

Comment: There are actually Two Laws of Total Probability. One version is the unconditional one. The other version which Dilip mentioned is the "Conditioned" version. I overlooked the fact that Patrick used P(X=x) for discrete instead of f(x) for continuous since it was already clear to me how to proceed at that point.

Answer (score -1):

Your integrated needs to be: $e^{-3x}f_X(x)$ and so the result follows from the [law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). Also, the sum you wrote as being equal to the integral is not correct.  I am not the best person to explain the theory behind the integral being equal to a limit of Riemann sums but just know that your sum does not make sense because the sample space for $X$ is **not discrete**.

Comment: And for the same reason, Pr[X=x]=Pr[Y>5,X=x]=0 for every x.

Comment: I don't know why but it took me a second to figure out what exactly you were saying...

Comment: How on earth does the OP's answer $P\{Y > 5\} = \int_0^\infty e^{-3x}dx = \frac{1}{3}$ follow from the _law of total probability?_ He hasn't even used the distribution of $X$ anywhere!

Comment: Yeah I definitely meant to say 'my' or 'the'. Oops.

Comment: Patrick, you are missing the point that **even if** $X$ is a discrete random variable, the sum that the OP has written makes no sense: adding up conditional probabilities conditioned on different events is plain wrong. Also, as Did pointed out to you but you seem not to have understood even after taking a second to understand it, $e^{-3x}\mathbb{Pr}[X=x] =\mathbb{Pr}[Y\gt 5,X=x]$ which _you_ state must be the integrand, has value $0$ everywhere and so the integral must also have value $0$.

Comment: Wow, I see my error.  I thought of $\mathbb{Pr}[X=x]$ as the density function which is definitely wrong.  Also, my point about the summation was not how summing up conditional probabilities conditioned on different events is wrong but just how a **sum** over a continuous variable does not make sense at all.